# How do I get the "title" of an anchor tag using BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can't figure out how to get the title on the anchor. 
Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

laptops = 'http://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops'


def scrape():
    page = requests.get('http://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/computers/laptops')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    links = soup("a", {"class":"title"})

    for link in links:
        print(link.prettify())


scrape()
```

Example of result:

```
<a class="title" href="/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/251" title="Asus VivoBook X441NA-GA190">
 Asus VivoBook X4...
</a>

<a class="title" href="/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/252" title="Prestigio SmartBook 133S Dark Grey">
 Prestigio SmartB...
</a>

<a class="title" href="/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone/product/253" title="Prestigio SmartBook 133S Gold">
 Prestigio SmartB...
</a>
```

How do I get the "title"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes like `title` are accessible via subscription or the `.attrs` dictionary on an element:

```
for link in links:
    print(link['title'])
```

See the [BeautifulSoup documentation on *Attributes*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes).

For the given URL this produces:

```
Asus VivoBook X441NA-GA190
Prestigio SmartBook 133S Dark Grey
Prestigio SmartBook 133S Gold
Aspire E1-510
Lenovo V110-15IAP
Lenovo V110-15IAP
Hewlett Packard 250 G6 Dark Ash Silver
# ... etc
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Thanks for pointing me to the correct page in the documentation.